# If $ range(T) \cap range(U)= \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace $ then $\left\lbrace T,U \right\rbrace$ are linearly independent set.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces and let $T$ and $U$ be non-zero linear transformations from $V$ to $W$.  If $ range(T)  \cap range(U)= \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace $ then show that $\left\lbrace T,U \right\rbrace$ are linearly independent set of $L\left(V,W \right)$.

Comment: Suppose they are linearly dependent. Then one is a scalar multiple of the other. Can you use this to find a non-zero vector in the intersection of their ranges?

Comment: Can we prove it straight instead of proof of contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There is a vector $x$ for which $Tx \neq 0$.  For any $a,b \in \Bbb R$, we have
$$
(aT + bU)x = 0 \iff\\
a(Tx) = -b(Ux)
$$
but $Tx \in range(T) \setminus \{0\}$.